# Imparfait ou plus-que-parfait ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

Pourriez-vous me dire laquelle de ces phrases est correcte :

> J’avais beau essayer de me concentrer, mais je n’ai pas réussi.

ou

> J’avais eu beau essayer de me concentrer, mais je n’ai pas réussi.

Je parle d'un jour où j'ai passé un examen.

Comment: @ba Non, "avoir beau" doit être suivi de l'infinitif.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La première est correcte avec le passé composé; cependant l'utilisation de « mais » est redondante ;

> J’ai eu beau essayer de me concentrer, je n’ai pas réussi.

On examine la définition de la locution « avoir beau » d'abord ;

> B. [L'idée dominante est celle de **chose accomplie dans un but**<sup>1</sup> (exprimée par avoir beau) et de **déception parce que le but n'est pas atteint** (exprimée par la proposition subséquente)]
>    Avoir beau + inf. (avec valeur concessive).
>
> - L'oncle Édouard a eu beau faire, beau s'évertuer, s'époumoner... ils démordaient pas de leur avis.
> - J'ai eu beau donner de la voix, personne, hélas, n'est venu me détacher.
> - J'ai eu beau chercher, je n'ai pas trouvé de solution :
> - J'avais eu beau chercher du haut de la crête les feux de la gare du plantier, pas moyen, la nuit me poussait dans le dos...
> - « Je suis sûr que Simon m'a menti. Il a eu beau jurer, il ne vaut pas mieux que les autres. (...) »
> - Vous avez eu beau vous entourer de précautions, nous voilà classés comme anticommunistes; ...

Aucun des exemples du TLFi ci-dessus ne contient la conjonction de coordination « mais » ; on comprend cela à partir de la définition : cette locution s'emploie selon un schéma ; la locution exprime l'idée d'une action qui est effectué dans le but de provoquer un résultat **mais** lequel est résultat qui ne sera pas obtenu ; l'opposition qu'exprime cette conjonction est contenue dans la locution.

« Mais » est utilisé pour refuser ce qui est dit dans la proposition qui précède, pour le rectifier, cependant dans ce cas, où on utilise « avoir beau », il n'y a rien à refuser, rien à rectifier. Cela est la raison pour laquelle un « mais » dans ce contexte donne une impression de logique scabreuse.

<sup>1</sup><sub>J'ai dû modifier légèrement la définition du dictionnaire ; elle avait un défaut ([avoir beau](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?61;s=1253403795;r=3;nat=;sol=0;)) : B. [L'idée dominante est celle de chose espérée (exprimée par avoir beau) et de déception (exprimée par la proposition subséquente)] ; « avoir beau » n'exprime pas quelque chose de défini, encore moins la chose espérée, mais l'action accomplie dans le but de la chose espérée et l'idée que le but ne sera pas atteint ; la chose espérée est exprimée par la seconde proposition.</sub>